# Open file failed, permission in manifest done

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, sd-card

In order for my app to run, it needs to open a txt file which I had saved into the phone's memory, and use the data in it.

I had put the permission in the Manifest, above the Application, and had put the path I believe to be the correct one. The program cannot run and logcat gives

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/TestDaten/input.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is some of the code.

In Manifest:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_"></uses-permission>
```

In the MainActivity

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    // Storage Permissions
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
           // Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }
AudioAnalyzer aa = new AudioAnalyzer();
    Button button;


    private View.OnClickListener runfilter = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                double[] input = readFile("/storage/TestDaten/input.txt");
                
                int i;
                double inputd = input[0];
                for (i=0;i<input.length-1; i++){
                    inputd = input[i];
                }


                isDetected(aa.EventAnalyzer(inputd));
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonrun);
        button.setOnClickListener(runfilter);
        
        verifyStoragePermissions(this);
    }

    public double[] readFile(String fname) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File(fname);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        List<Double> collection = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scanner.hasNextDouble())
        { 
            double number = scanner.nextDouble();
            collection.add(number);
        }

        scanner.close();
        return toPrimitive(collection.toArray(new Double[collection.size()]));
    }
public double[] toPrimitive(Double[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (array.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        final double[] result = new double[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            result[i] = array[i].doubleValue();
        }
        return result;}


    private void isDetected(int a){


        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence t0 = "No breathing";
        CharSequence t1 = "Normal breathing";
        CharSequence t2 = "Snoring";
        CharSequence t3 = "Apnea!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast0 = Toast.makeText(context, t0, duration);
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, t1, duration);
        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, t2, duration);
        Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(context, t3, duration);

        if(a==0)
            toast0.show();
        if(a==1)
            toast1.show();
        if(a==2)
            toast2.show();
        if(a==3)
            toast3.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Open File from sd card in Android** ( For reference )
Just open your main XML file and paste below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My BOOK"
        android:onClick="book"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now open your java file and paste below code:

```
package sel.listG; //package name

import java.io.File;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      }
      public void book(View v)
      {
//your pdf file path
            File file=new File("/sdcard/xxxx.pdf");
            if(file.exists())
            {
                  Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//set pdf to doc if you want to open doc
                  i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  try
                  {
                  startActivity(i);
                  }
                  catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                  {
//if pdf reader not found than open browser to download pdf reader
                        Intent i1=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en"));
                        startActivity(i1);
                  }
            }
            else
            {
//if pdf not found on given location
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "xxxx.pdf not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
      }
}
```

Now run your code.

P.S. The code stated regards to Pdf file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But instead of viewing the content, I just want to use the file content for calculations. I need to simulate real-time values using saved values.